# Function for comparing colums in a dataframe, giving information about existing differences

Tags: r, compare, difference

I'm trying to write a function to compare the values of two colums (**x** and **y**) in every row of a dataframe. The function shall compare line by line if the values are identical, allowing a specified tolerance **z** for each pair of values. 
identical() doesn't help because it doesn't allow small differences.
Nor  can I use all.equal(), because its "tolerance"-parameter relates to the mean difference across all rows, how the following example demonstrates.

```
> df <- data.frame("x"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "y"=c(2,7,3,4,5))
> df$diff_x_y <- df$x-df$y
> df
  x y diff_x_y
1 1 2       -1
2 2 7       -5
3 3 3        0
4 4 4        0
5 5 5        0
> all.equal(df$x, df$y, scale=1,tolerance=4)
[1] TRUE
>
```

So this is what I've made up so far:

```
fun <- function (x, y, z) 
{
  diff <- abs(x-y)                            # compute difference for each row
  tolerance <- ifelse(diff <= z, TRUE, FALSE) # test whether difference <= tolerance
  return(summary(tolerance))                  
}
```

This works fine for the example dataframe from above:

```
> fun(df$x,df$y,1)
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
logical       1       4       0
```

Now I want the function to give me some information about the existing differences. I image something like this:

```
difference  frequency
1:10        4
11:100      30
101:1000    350
```

"difference" is supposed to define an adjustable values range of the differences and "frequency" shall display the number of rows with the corresponding difference.
Other suggestions for the way of returning more detailed information about the differences are welcome. Notice that my original dataframe contains about 2 mio. rows, of whom some may differ significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest way imho is to use cut:

```
df$diff.cat  <- cut(abs(df$x-df$y),breaks=c(0,1,10,100,1000),right = FALSE)
```

the right = FALSE switch is making the intervals include the left (small) margin -

0 <=  first interval < 1
       1 <= second interval < 10 etc.

you can adjust the intervals of course
you can see the frequencies with

```
table(df$diff.cat)
```

so basically for:

```
df <- data.frame("x"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "y"=c(2,7,3,4,5))

table(cut(abs(df$x-df$y),breaks=c(0,1,10,100,1000),right = FALSE))
```

will give:

```
  [0,1)      [1,10)    [10,100) [100,1e+03) 
      3           2           0           0
```